# Get the Z values of existing lineStringZ with PyQGIS?

Tags: qgis-plugins, geometry, polyline-creation, pyqgis-3

I can get the values of 3D QgsPoints with mypoint.get().z() When I iterate through a layer to get a specific polyline and then iterate through the polyline to get the start and end points- **start_point = QgsPoint(geom[0])** I get a QgsPointXY and no Z values.   They are there until the iteration geom[0] and then *poof* gone.

Is there a way to include the z values with something other than QgsPoint(geom[-1])?

My related question is [Changing the coordinate value of a Pointz object with python](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/304234/changing-the-coordinate-value-of-a-pointz-object-with-python) - which is actually how I got the points to create the polyLine

I am taking this route next 
 [Adding Z value from a Point field to a LineString using pyqgis](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/260206/adding-z-value-from-a-point-field-to-a-linestring-using-pyqgis)

Below is the code I ran in the Python Console.   The output is also below.

```
layer = iface.activeLayer()
print(layer)
all_features = layer.getFeatures()
layer.startEditing()
for pipe in all_features:

        if pipe['name'] == '1212_1211':
            print('found it ********\n  ')
            pipe_id = pipe.id()

            geom = pipe.geometry()
            print(geom)
            new_feat = QgsFeature()
            geom = pipe.geometry().asPolyline()
            start_point = QgsPoint(geom[0])
            end_point = QgsPoint(geom[-1])
            print (start_point)
            print (start_point.x())
```

***OUTPUT***

```
<qgis._core.QgsVectorLayer object at 0x000001767C312EE8>
found it ********

<QgsGeometry: LineStringZ (26138560.91000000014901161 643574.7099999999627471 778.20000000000004547, 26138558.94000000134110451 643563.81000000005587935 0)>
<QgsPoint: Point (26138560.91000000014901161 643574.7099999999627471)>
26138560.91
```

***UPDATE***

I found a great chunk of code from this site that made this work for QGIS 3 - geom.constGet() is the key below. [How to access shapefile m-values with pyqgis?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/141468/how-to-access-shapefile-m-values-with-pyqgis/216339?r=SearchResults#216339)

```
layer = iface.activeLayer()
print(layer)
all_features = layer.getFeatures()
layer.startEditing()
for pipe in all_features:

    if pipe['name'] == '1212_1211':
        print('found it ********\n  ')
        pipe_id = pipe.id()

        geom = pipe.geometry()
        line = geom.constGet() #line returns a QgsLineString object

        z = line.zAt(0) # z value of first vertex
        print(str(z))
```

Answer (score 2):

It's a bit silly but as I look in the `QgsPoint` constructor like here: [QGIS Python API: QgsPoint](https://qgis.org/pyqgis/3.0/core/Point/QgsPoint.html)

I think you need to provide the 3 coordinates of the point in order to create a 3D point, if you only send a geom and if the wkbtype is unknown, he will cast it as a 2D point. 
So maybe try to explicitly give the 3 coordinates of the point before calling `QgsPoint`, something like :

```
QgsPoint(mypoint.get().x(),mypoint.get().y(),mypoint.get().z())
```

and then you do your stuff on `mypoint.get().z()`. There is also a method called `addZvalue()`.

Comment: Thanks Maximilien :) I did use that to make the points for the polyline  but when I tried to get the points (vertices) from the polyline they came out as QgsPointXY points without z values.  I used the z = line.zAt(i)  to walk through the line and take out the x,y,z values.  Then I rebuilt the QgsPoint from them and used the setGeometry to update the Polyline.

Answer (score 0):

I have same issue with all, I have calculated with function `z(start_point($geometry))`.

It's OK for my database.