# Adding elevation to point in PyQGIS?

Tags: elevation, pyqgis-3

I am trying to add elevation to a 2D point in a QGIS 3 plugin, preferably in a concise and straightforward way. Not finding this easy.

I think part of the problem is that in QGIS 3, `fromPoint()` has been renamed to `fromPointXY()`. I am not very clear on how to create 3D point geometry.

I have tried a number of variations without finding one which works and have not been able to find a suitable example online.

Basically what I want to achieve is `PointXY + elevation -> Point`, which I would expect to be something like this:

```
z = 1.0 # or whatever

for l in selectedLayers: # for each selected layer
  if l.geometryType() == QgsWkbTypes.PointGeometry: # point layer

    l.startEditing()
    feat = l.getFeatures()

    for f in feat: # each feature

      # Get existing geometry...
      geom = f.geometry()
      pt = geom.asPoint() # returns PointXY

      # Replace with 3D geometry...
      pt3D = QgsPoint(pt.x(), pt.y(), z)
      geom = QgsGeometry.fromPointXY(pt3D) # error, because pt is 3D
      f.setGeometry(geom)

      l.updateFeature(f)

    l.commitChanges()
```

How do I do this?

---

For the benefit of others this is now resolved using the answer(s) below.

I am now adding the elevation like this:

```
f.setGeometry( QgsPoint(pt.x(), pt.y(), z) ) # x, y, z
```

It turns out that my problem was not so much adding the elevation, as knowing when I had successfully added it.

Comment: That contains 2 x ')' and 1 x '(' so syntactically I wouldn't expect that to work as written. It seems clear from the documentation that QgSPointXY is specifically a 2D point and does not support a z dimension. If you mean replace 'geom = QgsGeometry.fromPointXY(pt3D)' with something like 'geom = QgsGeometry.fromPointXY( QgsPointXY(1, 2), 3)' then no, that doesn't work.

Comment: QgsPointXY is specifically a 2D point and does not support a z dimension. This seems clear from the QGIS API documentation and I have tried it. 'pt3D = QgsPointXY((1,2), 3)' results in a TypeError.

Comment: Please write a self-answer in the area reserved for answers rather than in the area reserved for questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need create a QgsGeometry object.

Add minimal sample for setGeometry 3D

```
feature = QgsFeature()
feature.setAttributes([lon, lat, alt])
feature.setGeometry(QgsPoint(lon, lat, alt))
layer.addFeatures([feature])
```

The original code is in my github,where a lot of layers are in 3d

https://github.com/All4Gis/QGISFMV/blob/35eb3f59b4d6423a375d7a04d54b6765dcc5c986/code/utils/QgsFmvLayers.py#L515

And for get to z value from feature,you can use something like that:

```
feature.geometry().vertexAt(0).z()
```

Comment: Thanks. Understood on the QgsGeometry object. It may be that I am successfully adding the elevation but I just cannot access the z value to check it. If I try to get the geometry using asPoint() it returns a 2D point and any z value is discarded. The API documentation is clear on this. So... how do I get the full coordinates of a 3D point?? I want to do something like this: 'QgsMessageLog.logMessage(str(f.geometry().z()))' but that doesn't work. I am getting 'AttributeError: 'QgsGeometry' object has no attribute 'z''.

Comment: update my answer

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking at the Geometry of a feature you will have to do something like:

```
val_x = geom.get().x()
val_y = geom.get().y()
val_z = geom.get().z()
```

[How to get the Z values of existing lineStringZ with pyqgis?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/305624/how-to-get-the-z-values-of-existing-linestringz-with-pyqgis)